# UBUNTU:How to NOT run vsftpd at boot time... ?

Tags: ubuntu, boot

HI,

Im trying to prevent vsftpd to start at boot time and didnt find how until now...
Im using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.
I have installing vfstpd via apt-get
I have removed the init script from init.d directory and did the following command :

```
update-rc.d vsftp remove
update-rc.d vsftpd remove
```

but vsftpd still run at boot time...

I would like to know how to prevent it to start at boot time and how to start it at boot time in case I change my mind.

thanks you all

Answer (score 4):

Starting with Ubuntu 11.04 you can also use

```
echo manual >> /etc/init/vsftpd.override
```

Reference: https://askubuntu.com/a/20347

Answer (score 2):

According to some search result on [ubuntu forums](http://newyork.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1519273) the best way is to

```
mv /etc/init/vsftpd.conf /etc/init/vsftpd.conf.off
```

Comment: Starting with Ubuntu 11.04 you can also use `echo manual >> /etc/init/vsftpd.override`. Reference: [http://askubuntu.com/a/20347]

Comment: You should make that a new answer. When I posted my answer (2010) ubuntu (20)11.04 wasn't available yet.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it's like this for you but personally I use

> sysv-rc-conf

which is the visual editor that let you enable or disable your rc.d easily.

Comment: thanks but I have been using this one too and i think its doing quite the same job of update-rc.d and its doenst work too. vsftpd still launch at boot time.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the /etc/init/ scripts. Basically, if it's started via upstart, you just have to delete or comment the "start" statement on the top of the vsftpd related file.

Answer (score 1):

Vstpd demon is controlled by new service: [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/).

You can turn off it by editing `/etc/init/vsfpd.conf` file and simple commenting 2 lines (in my case line 7 and 8). It should be something like that:

```
start on (filesystem
        and net-device-up IFACE!=lo)
```

Or you can use these command:

```
sudo sed -i.old -e '/start/,+1s/^/#/' /etc/init/vsftpd.conf
```

It comments the line with word `start` and the next line. Before changes it makes copy of the file and saves it under the name: `vsftpd.conf.old`.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for `vsftpd` references in /etc:

```
grep vsftpd -R /etc
```

It may be started from `/etc/rc.local` for example.

Answer (score 0):

If there is not a `listen=yes` or `listen_ipv6=yes` in your `/etc/vsftpd.conf`, then the service will not be started.

Answer (score 0):

with root permission

```
vim /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

set

```
listen=NO
```

then

```
service vsftpd restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo systemctl disable vsftpd.service
```

> This will remove the symbolic link that indicated that the service should be started automatically.
>   (Source: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units)

Works, if you use systemctl for autostart management.

> **How to find out, if you use systemctl:**
>
> 1. start your server ( vsftpd.conf start )
> 2. if the line says [...] starten [...] (**via systemctl**), you have the answer

Comment: That's a lot of quoting to end up with a generic systemd answer.  How about making it specific to vsftpd?